# How to differentiate $f(t)\theta(t)$, the product of a function with the Heaviside unit step?

Tags: proof-verification, distribution-theory, signal-processing, dirac-delta

What is the derivative (in the engineer's or distributional sense) of the causal function $f(t)\theta(t)$, where $\theta$ is the Heaviside unit step function?

I've seen the formula $f'(t)\theta(t)+f(0)\delta(t)$, where $\delta$ is Dirac's delta. This looks like a kind of "product rule": differentiating the product gives $f'\theta+f\theta'$, but $\theta'$ is $\delta$, and $\color{blue}{f(t)\delta(t)=f(0)\delta(t)}$.

If this is right, I don't understand the following argument, from the solutions manual to Oppenheim and Wilsky's *Signals and Systems*. The solutions manual says the derivative of the function $2e^{-3t}\theta(t-1)$ is

$$-6e^{-3t}\theta(t-1)+\color{red}{2}\delta(t-1)$$

It's the second term I don't understand. Using the "product rule" heuristic, the second term should be $2e^{-3t}\delta(t-1)$, which using the blue formula above gives $\color{red}{2e^{-3}}$ times the delayed delta function, not just twice the delayed delta function.

Is the solutions manual wrong?

Comment: One cannot differentiate the Heaviside step function in the classical sense (since $\theta\notin C^{1}(\mathbb{R})$), thus one must opt to deduce the distributional derivative.
 
I presume that you define

$$\theta(t)=\begin{cases}1,&t>0, \\ 0,& t\le 0.\end{cases}$$

Thus, for all test functions $\phi\in\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$, one can compute, for $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$,
$$\begin{aligned} \langle (f\theta)',\phi\rangle&=-\langle f\theta,\phi'\rangle
\\
&=-\langle\theta,f\phi'\rangle
\\
&=-\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)\phi'(t)\,dt\end{aligned}$$

Comment: @user3482534: yes, I'm working in engineer's notation, where it is customary to give calculations and formulas like I did. Can you translate your comment into a more direct answer to the question about whether the solutions manual is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right.

Indeed, 
\begin{align}
\langle (e^{-3t}\theta(t-1))',\phi\rangle 
&= -\langle e^{-3t}\theta(t-1),\phi'\rangle
\\ 
&= -\int_1^\infty e^{-3t}\phi'(t)dt
\\
&= -e^{-3t}\phi(t)\big|_1^{\infty}-3\int_1^\infty e^{-3t}\phi(t)dt 
\\
&= e^{-3}\phi(1) - 3 \langle e^{-3t}\theta(t-1),\phi \rangle 
\\
&= e^{-3}\langle\delta_1,\phi\rangle - 3 \langle e^{-3t}\theta(t-1),\phi \rangle. 
\end{align}

Hence, we can conclude that
$$(e^{-3t}\theta(t-1))' =- 3   e^{-3t}\theta(t-1) +e^{-3} \delta_1. $$

I think the authors of the manual forgot that they were working with $\theta(t-1)$, not just $\theta(t)$.

Comment: Distributions are scalars, not functions. In the resultant equation in your response, $e^{-3}\delta_1$ is a scalar because $\delta_1$ is a distribution of $\phi$. But the other term in your equation would have been a scalar as well, if it hadn't been for the $t$-dependent term $-3e^{-3t}$ that converts the scalar-valued Heaviside distribution $\theta(t-1)$ to a function. Am I right?

Comment: The question is about $f(t)\theta(t)$. Your response is about the distribution $(f(t)\theta(t))[\phi]$. How do you ensure $f(t)\theta(t)=(f(t)\theta(t))[\phi]$?

Comment: @IvanNepomnyashchikh Distributions are not scalars, they are linear functionals over the space of test functions. If you have two distributions $Q$ and $P$, then they are equal if and only if (by definition!) for each test function $\phi$ you have $P[\phi]=Q[\phi]$.

Comment: Thank you @TZakrevskiy. For the first part: thank you for correcting me. For the second part, I think either one of us is wrong. From your response, I conclude that you think that the original question is concerned about the derivative of the product $f(t)\theta(t)$, where $f(t)$ is a function and $\theta(t)$ is a Heaviside DISTRIBUTION. But I think the original question is concerned about the derivative of the product $f(t)\theta(t)$, where $f(t)$ is a function and $\theta(t)$ is the Heaviside FUNCTION. That's why I'm asking how you ensure the equality between a function and a distribution.

Comment: @IvanNepomnyashchikh Heaviside's function does not have a derivative in the usual sense, only in the sense of distributions (they are sometimes called "generalized functions", by the way). For $L^1_{loc}$ functions such as $\theta(t)$ (they all define a distribution) it is rather common to "blur"/"forget" the difference between the function and its distribution counterpart. This leads to common mistake where people try to see $\delta$-distribution as something $L^1_{loc}$, which is not the case.

Comment: @IvanNepomnyashchikh if you want a Bourbaki-style formalism and consider $\theta$ as an $L^1_{loc}$ function, you define an embedding $i:L^1_{loc}(\Bbb R) \to D'(\Bbb R)$ and a multiplication $p: C^\infty(\Bbb R)\times D'(\Bbb R) \to D'(\Bbb R)$. Then you prove $\left(p(e^{-3t}, i(\theta(t-1)))\right)' = e^{-3}\delta_1 - 3p(e^{-3t}, i(\theta(t-1)))$ by applying these distributions to an artbitrary test function.