# rewriting a piecewise function in terms of the Heaviside step function and then taking the derivative

Tags: functions, dirac-delta

Okay, so I was following along [this document](http://people.math.binghamton.edu/grads/kaminski/math371_winter12/HeaviSide.pdf) (edit: [archived document](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506233014/http://people.math.binghamton.edu/grads/kaminski/math371_winter12/HeaviSide.pdf)), and I had a couple of questions.
So I understand the logic of turning a function off then turning it on.

**Question 1:** But what if we took this function:
$$f(t)=\begin{Bmatrix}t^3 & 0\leq t < 2\\ 5 & 2\leq t < 20\\ e^{-t} & 20 \leq t\end{Bmatrix}$$
which the document says would be converted to:
$$f(t)=t^3H(t-0)-t^3H(t-2)+5H(t-2)-5H(t-20)+e^{-t}H(t-20)$$
and rewrit it like this instead:
$$g(t)=\begin{Bmatrix}t^3 & t < 2\\ 5 & 2\leq t < 20\\ e^{-t} & 20 \leq t\end{Bmatrix}$$
How would I rewrit that function, because it doesn't look like $t^3$ is ever "turned on", and only functions that have been "turned on" can be "turned off". So would that function be rewritten as:
$$g(t)=5H(t-2)-5H(t-20)+e^{-t}H(t-20)$$

**Question 2a:** Also, for the original rewritten piecewise function, how would I take the derivative of that function? I know that
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x}H(x)=\delta(x)$$
so if I wanted to take $f'(x)$, would it just be:
$$f'(t) = 3t^2H(t-0)+t^3H'(t-0)-3t^2H(t-2)-t^3H'(t-2)+0+5H'(t-2)-0-5H'(t-20)-e^{-t}H(t-20)+e^{-t}H'(t-20)$$ 
$$= 3t^2H(t-0)+t^3\delta(t-0)-3t^2H(t-2)-t^3\delta(t-2)+5\delta(t-2)-5\delta(t-20)-e^{-t}H(t-20)+e^{-t}\delta(t-20)$$
$$= 3t^2H(t)+t^3\delta(t)-3t^2H(t-2)-t^3\delta(t-2)+5\delta(t-2)-5\delta(t-20)-e^{-t}H(t-20)+e^{-t}\delta(t-20)$$

**Question 2b:** Is $$H(t-0) = H(t) = 1$$ and is $$\delta(t-0) = \delta(t)=0 $$?

Comment: Draw the function, the Dirac delta distribution $C \delta(t-a)$ appears at each jump when diffentiating.

Comment: The difference between your $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ is that your $f(t)$ is undefined for $t<0$ and your $g(t)$ is defined as $t^3$ for $t<0$ (i.e. $t^3$ is "turned on" in a sense at $t=-\infty$).

Comment: So the $t^3$ term in $g(t)$ can be written as $t^3\,(1-\theta(t-2))$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to start with the end, 2b, $H(t-0) = H(t)$ is one for $t\geq 0$ and zero in $t<0$

Regarding $\delta(t)$ it is not a function but a distribution and it is definitely not zero.

for question 1:

$$f(t)=t^3-t^3H(t-2)+5H(t-2)-5H(t-20)+e^{-t}H(t-20)
$$

for 2a

$$f'(t)=3t^2-3t^2H(t-2) + t^3 \delta(t-2)+5\delta(t-2)-5\delta(t-20)-e^{-t}H(t-20)+ e^{-t} \delta(t-20)
$$

we can simplify since $\delta(t)$ is zero away from $t$ to get

$$f(t)=3t^2-3t^2H(t-2) + 8 \delta(t-2)+5\delta(t-2)-5\delta(t-20)-e^{-t}H(t-20)+ e^{-20} \delta(t-20)
$$

Comment: For your answer to question 1, are you saying the answer WOULDN'T change, because the f(x) you've written is exactly the same as the one given in the document I linked. To clarify, I was asking if my interpretation for this new g(x) was correct, and the difference is that the bounds for one of the functions (t^3) has been changed.

Comment: also, is your answer for 2a meant to read f'(x), rather than f(x), because otherwise I don't follow.

Comment: I get it now, thanks a lot. I tried upvoting your response, but nothing happened? But thanks a lot for the response, dude.

Comment: there is no $t^3$ alone, you lost a $H(t)$

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mark Joshi and thank you for your comments @reuns. I'm wondering if either of you can be so kind to clarify for me, please, the answer for the question 2.a. Namely, which terms are functions there and which terms are distributions. If all of them are distributions, then $f'(t)$ is just a number - not a function. That doesn't seem right. Aslo, why $t^3$ becomes $8$ and why $e^{-t}$ becomes $e^{-20}$? My question stems from the discussion here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2165666/693799