# How to prove that $f(t)\delta(t) = f(0) \delta(t)$?

Tags: dirac-delta, step-function

I found this equation in thi s question [How to differentiate $f(t)\theta(t)$, the product of a function with the Heaviside unit step?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2165666/how-to-differentiate-ft-thetat-the-product-of-a-function-with-the-heavisi)
$$ f(t)\delta(t) = f(0) \delta(t) \tag{1} $$
Now I have a similar formula that needs to be simplified, its expression is like $ H(-t)g(-t-a) \delta(t)$, where H is the unit step function. Can it be simplified to:
$$ 
\begin{align}
 H(-t)g(-t-a) \delta(t) =& H(0) g(-a) \delta(t) \\
=&g(-a) \delta(t) \tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

I think it's right, but I don't know how to prove eq(1) and is the usage in eq(2) correct?

Comment: I would say that it's ill-advised to multiply a delta function by a function which is not continuous on some neighborhood of $0$. Think of $\delta$ as a function on functions (called a functional) defined by $\delta(f) = f(0)$. What should $\delta(H)$ be? Is it $0$? Is it $1$? Is it $\frac{1}{2}$? There's no good answer because the value of $H$ at $0$ is pretty much an arbitrary choice.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins While I don't like to write this way, it's a must at this point. This function is produced by the derivative of g*H*H.

Comment: What question are you referring to? Your TeX code seems to be not working.

Comment: As Charles pointed out the product of dirac delta with function not continous at zero is generally speaking not ideal. We might be able to help you if you provide us the original function whose derivative yields the expression. You wrote $gHH$ but somehow $a$ needs to come into this.

Comment: Notice that $HH = H^2 = H$, its derivative is $\delta$, not $H\delta$. Similarly, if you have $u(t) = g(t)\,H(t)\,H(-t)$, then since either $H(t)$ or $H(-t)$ is $0$, you get that $u(t)=0$ so its derivative is $0$

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you cannot simply multiply a Dirac delta with the Heaviside function using the standard theory of distributions, i.e., Schwartz' theory. This theory is generally linear, i.e., you can only do linear operations on distributions. Multiplication; $f.\theta$, where $f$ is a distribution, is only defined if $\theta$ is a smooth function, which is not the case for the Heaviside function. There are several scenarios in physics that require such an operation. There are some extensions of Schwartz' theory that can allow for such an operation; see, e.g., [Colombeau algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colombeau_algebra).