# Is my derivation of the derivative of a product of the Heaviside function and a function correct? (A follow-up question)

Tags: derivatives, distribution-theory, convolution, dirac-delta, step-function

That's a follow-up question to the accepted answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2165666/how-to-differentiate-ft-thetat-the-product-of-a-function-with-the-heavisi?rq=1) post.

After some thinking, I ended up deriving the derivative differently. I'm wondering if the dear Math stack exchange community can tell me whether it is wrong or not please.

Here goes my derivation.

Assume we have some continuous function $f(x)$ defined on the interval $[0, \infty)$ and it doesn't go to infinity when $x$ goes to infinity.

I multiply it by the Heaviside function to expand it to the entire $x$ axis: $f(x)H(x)$. Here, $H(x)$ is equal to $1$ at $x=0$.

I want to differentiate that product.

[The post that I cited](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2165666/how-to-differentiate-ft-thetat-the-product-of-a-function-with-the-heavisi?rq=1) states that I can't do that and that I have to convert the product to a distribution first. However, the post doesn't specify how one does the conversion to preserve the physical meaning of the product $f(x)H(x)$.

I have come up with the following conversion procedure. I'm going to mollify the product: $(f(x)H(x))*\phi(x)$. Here, $\phi(x)$ is the mollifier and $*$ stands for convolution.

Convolution can be considered as a distribution (I read that in Wikipedia).

Now we have the distribution $\langle(f(x)H(x)), \phi \rangle$ that approximates the product $f(x)H(x)$ preserving its physical meaning and we can differentiate it:

$$\langle(f(x)H(x))', \phi \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty (f(x)H(x))' \phi(x)dx$$

Here:

1. $H(x)=0$ for $x \in (-\infty, 0)$, therefore, I can change the integration limit to $[0,   \infty)$.
2. $H(x)=1=const$ for $x \in [0, \infty)$, therefore, $(f(x)H(x))'=H(x)f(x)'$ for $x \in [0, \infty)$.

With that in mind we have the following:
$$\langle(f(x)H(x))', \phi \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty (f(x)H(x))' \phi(x)dx = \int_0^\infty f(x)' \ 1 \ \phi(x)dx = \int_0^\infty f(x)' \phi(x)dx = (f(x=0)' \phi(x=0)) = \langle \delta, (f(x)'\phi(x) \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x) f(x)' \phi(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty (f(x)' \delta(x)) \phi(x)dx = \langle(f(x)' \delta), \phi \rangle$$

I'm wondering if this derivation is correct.
If positive, then I have the follow up questions.

1. Why my result is not the same as in [the post that I cited](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2165666/how-to-differentiate-ft-thetat-the-product-of-a-function-with-the-heavisi?rq=1)?
2. How can the function $f(x)$ defined on the interval $x \in [0, \infty)$ be under the integral with the integration limits $(-\infty, \infty)$?
3. What if the function $f(x)$ were defined on the interval $x \in (0, \infty)$? How would it affect the derivation?

Comment: Why do you "
Assume we have some continuous function $f(x)$ defined on the interval $[0, \infty)$"? You are not working with distributions on $(0, \infty)$ but on $(-\infty, \infty).$ At least, $f$ should be defined on a neighborhood of $[0, \infty),$ i.e. on $[-\epsilon, \infty)$ for some $\epsilon>0.$

Comment: Thank you @md2perpe. I assume that because the only reason to multiply a function $f(x)$ by the Heaviside function I know of is when $f(x)$ is a piecewise function. I learnt that from this YouTube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OUNvg5AnLfA). So, I just came up with the easiest piecewise $f(x)$ I could think of. Moreover, the post that I referenced in my question says nothing about $f(x)$ had to be defined on the neighborhood of the point of interest. Still, your comment does make sense and I have a similar concern. That concern is reflected in my 3 question (at the end of my post).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Your error

In your second step, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty (f(x)H(x))' \phi(x)dx = \int_0^\infty f(x)' \ 1 \ \phi(x)dx,$ you are not using the definition of distributional derivative. Remember that the definition is $\langle u', \phi \rangle := -\langle u, \phi' \rangle.$ Do *not* assume that you can just take the derivative of a function wherever the derivative is defined and use that. If it were that simple you would have $H'=0$ but the correct is $H'=\delta.$

#### Correct derivation

Let $f \in C^\infty([0, \infty)),$ meaning that $f \in C^\infty((0, \infty))$ and that the limits of all derivatives exist at $0.$ Let $f$ define a distribution by $\phi \mapsto \int_0^\infty f(x) \, \phi(x) \, dx$ for $\phi \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R).$ Let $f'$ denote the classical derivative of $f$ defined on $(0, \infty).$ Then the *distributional derivative* of $f,$ denoted by $Df$ is given by
$$
\langle Df, \phi \rangle
= -\langle f, \phi' \rangle
= -\int_0^\infty f(x) \, \phi'(x) \, dx
= -\left[ f(x) \, \phi(x) \right]_0^\infty + \int_0^\infty f'(x) \, \phi(x) \, dx
= f(0) \, \phi(0) + \langle f', \phi \rangle
= \langle f(0)\delta, \phi \rangle + \langle f', \phi \rangle
= \langle f' + f(0)\delta, \phi \rangle,
$$
i.e. $Df = f' + f(0)\delta.$

Comment: Thank you @md2perpe. You see, there're several subtle things here that you mentioned and that I don't quiet get.

Comment: The first one is that you call expression $\langle u', \phi \rangle := -\langle u, \phi' \rangle$ definition. Whereas to my knowledge, it's not a definition. I read somewhere that it is a derivation that involves integration by parts. And it is that derivation that dictates the restriction on $\phi$: $\phi$ must be a test function meaning that it is equal to $0$ at both $+\infty$ and $-\infty$. Otherwise, we have that other term from the integration by parts that is not zero. Isn't that right?

Comment: The second one is that I adopted my derivation from the derivation of the formula $H'=\delta$. In the later, one would change the integration limits from $(-\infty, \infty) $ to $ [0, \infty)$ simultaneously equalizing $H$ to $1$. That's pretty mush what I did except that I didn't use the $definition$ of the distributional derivative. And notice, my formula $\langle (fH)', \phi \rangle = \langle (f' \delta), \phi \rangle$ resembles the formula $\langle  H', \phi \rangle = \langle \delta, \phi \rangle$. That's why I decided my derivation might not be that wrong ...

Comment: @IvanNepomnyashchikh. The identity $\langle u', \phi \rangle = - \langle u, \phi' \rangle$ really is a definition. It is however based on integration by parts. A distribution is not a function, so you cannot apply integration by parts on it. But distributions are an extension of functions on which you can do it.

Comment: In the derivation of $H'=\delta$ one should start with the definition of distributional derivative, $\langle H', \phi \rangle = - \langle H, \phi' \rangle.$ Then, since $\langle H, \phi' \rangle$ is defined by an integral $\int_0^\infty \phi'(x) \, dx,$ one can use classical integration by parts and finally end up with $\phi(0)$ which can be written as $\langle \delta, \phi \rangle.$ So, $\langle H', \phi \rangle = \delta, \phi \rangle$ for all test functions, which imply $H' = \delta.$

Answer (score 0):

I found an error in my derivation: $$\int_0^{\infty} f(x)' \phi(x) dx \neq (f(x=0)'\phi(x=0))$$
With that in mind, my question doesn't bring any good to Math stack exchange. But md2perpe's answer and comments are very useful to mind which makes me uncertain about deleting my question.
I'll leave it for now.
If the moderators decide to delete it, I'll delete it.